# When calling method from other view controller, it becomes dealloc'd

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers.  We'll call them *listViewController* and *mapViewController*.  The listViewController shows first, a user taps a button that shows the mapViewController.  The user taps a button on a annotation which is where my problems start.

When the user taps a button on mapViewController, I would like to call a method listViewController and dismiss mapViewController. To do this I am using this code:

**mapViewController.m**

```
listViewController* lvc = [[listViewController alloc] initWithNibName:nil bundle:nil];
[lvc getInformation:StringParameter];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
```

However, when executing `getInformation` it seems that the listViewController class has been dealloc'd because all of the objects that I initialized in the `viewDidLoad` on listViewController are now nil including `self`, which just breaks everything.

I assume I'm creating the listViewController object incorrectly in mapViewController.  I've tried it with a nil for nibName with the same result.

Comment: You need to use a delegate pattern: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8606674/uimodaltransitionstylepartialcurl-doesnt-get-back-to-previous-state-not-dismi

Comment: Very similar question with several correct answers that will probably solve your issue http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24457936/warning-attempt-to-present-whose-view-is-not-in-the-window-hierarchy/24459150#24459150

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, Let me clear one thing. On listViewController, you presentViewController a mapViewcontroller right? And you want invoke getInformation of the instance from mapViewController. In the code you're added, you instantiate listViewController again. You have 2 different instance of listViewController.

Comment: Okay.  I think you're right.  How do I select the pre-existing instance then?

Comment: Several ways to send message. Such as delegate, notification, block callback. If you need detail about each case, add comment.

Comment: I've used NSNotification before, so I'll try that.  Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a delegate pattern:

In your `MapViewController.h` file:

```
@protocol MapViewControllerDelegate <NSObject>
-(void)dismissMe;
-(void)getInformation:(NSString *)stringParameter;

@end

@interface MapViewController : UIViewController
@property (weak)id <MapViewControllerDelegate> delegate;
@end
```

In your `MapViewController.m` file:

```
-(void)annotationButtonTap:(id)button
{
    [self.delegate getInformation:stringParameter];
    [self.delegate dismissMe];
}
```

In your `ListViewController.h`

```
#import "MapViewController.h"

@interface ListViewController : UIViewController <MapViewControllerDelegate>

-(void)dismissMe
{
    [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
}

-(void)getInformation:(NSString *)stringParameter
{
    //do whatever you plan with stringParameter
}
```

And somewhere in you `ListViewController.m` file where you create the `MapViewController` instance:

```
mapViewController = [[MapViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MapViewController" bundle:nil];
mapViewController.delegate = self;   //make sure you do this
```